# Dynamically updating list view from XML file at server in Android

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, adapter

I've an XML file present at server, I want to update my list view by using data present at XML file in server and whenever the data is updated in XML, it will reflect automatically in list. I've a code that's working fine separately but when i put the same code in my project it won't work.

Here is my code:

**ContactDetail.xml** The file to parse

```
<contact-detail>
<person>
    <name>Anshul Thakur</name>
    <phone>9882222225</phone>
    <email>anshul9@gmail.com</email>
    <image-url>https://anshulthakur939.000webhostapp.com/wp-admin/Genesis_App_Data/Contact_Data/me_small.jpg</image-url>
</person>
<person>
    <name>A Thakur</name>
    <phone>988000005</phone>
    <email>anshulth9@gmail.com</email>
    <image-url>https://anshulthakur939.000webhostapp.com/wp-admin/Genesis_App_Data/Contact_Data/me_small.jpg</image-url>
</person>
<person>
    <name>Arun Thakur</name>
    <phone>988111115</phone>
    <email>anshulth9@gmail.com</email>
    <image-url>https://anshulthakur939.000webhostapp.com/wp-admin/Genesis_App_Data/Contact_Data/me_small.jpg</image-url>
</person>
<person>
    <name>Sample</name>
    <phone>988222222</phone>
    <email>anshul939@gmail.com</email>
    <image-url>https://anshulthakur939.000webhostapp.com/wp-admin/Genesis_App_Data/Contact_Data/me_small.jpg</image-url>
</person>
<person>
    <name>Sample</name>
    <phone>982222222</phone>
    <email>anshu9@gmail.com</email>
    <image-url>https://anshulthakur939.000webhostapp.com/wp-admin/Genesis_App_Data/Contact_Data/default.jpg</image-url>
</person>
```

**SitesXMLPullParser.java**

```
package com.atechgeek.genesis.XMLPullParser;

import android.content.Context;

import com.atechgeek.genesis.HelperObj.ContactDetail;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Anshul Thakur on 7/27/2017.
 */

public class SitesXMLPullParser
{
    static final String KEY_PERSON = "person";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
    static final String KEY_IMAGE_URL = "image-url";
    public static List<ContactDetail> getContactDetailFromFile(Context ctx)
    {
        //List to return
        List<ContactDetail> contactDetails = new ArrayList<ContactDetail>();
        // temp holder for current <person> tag while parsing
        ContactDetail curContactDetail = null;
        // temp holder for current text value in between opening and closing tags while parsing
        String curText = "";
        try
        {
            //get Pull parser
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
            //get input file stream
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = ctx.openFileInput("ContactDetail.xml");
            //to read file
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
            //set the file as Input to XMLPullParser
            parser.setInput(reader);
            //get Initial value of Event
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            //Start Loop to get Events until we reach end of Document

            while(eventType!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
            {
                //get Current Tag
                String tagname=parser.getName();
                //handle diff EventType
                switch (eventType)
                {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_PERSON))
                        {
                            //if new contact is there <person> ....</person>
                            curContactDetail = new ContactDetail();
                        }
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        //grabs whole of data after starting tag to use in End_tag
                        curText=parser.getText();
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_PERSON))
                        {
                            //if </person> then all the contact of 1 person is fetched
                            //add it to list of Contacts
                            contactDetails.add(curContactDetail);
                        }
                        else if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_NAME))
                        {
                            //if </name> occurs then set contactDetails name as contact person name
                            curContactDetail.setName(curText);
                        }
                        else if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_PHONE))
                        {
                            //if </phone> occurs
                            curContactDetail.setPhone(Long.parseLong(curText));
                        }
                        else if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_EMAIL))
                        {
                            //if </email> occurs
                            curContactDetail.setEmail(curText);
                        }
                        else if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_IMAGE_URL))
                        {
                            //if </image-url> occurs
                            curContactDetail.setImage_url(curText);
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
             eventType = parser.next();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return contactDetails;
    }
}
```

**Downloader.java**

```
package com.atechgeek.genesis.XMLPullParser;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

/*
 * Helper class for downloading a file.
 */
public class Downloader {

    //Tag for Log statements
    private static String myTag = "StackSites";

    //Handler msg that represents we are posting a progress update.
    static final int POST_PROGRESS = 1;

    /************************************************
     * Download a file from the Internet and store it locally
     * 
     * @param URL - the url of the file to download
     * @param fos - a FileOutputStream to save the downloaded file to.
     ************************************************/
    public static void DownloadFromUrl(String URL, FileOutputStream fos) {  //this is the downloader method
        try {

            URL url = new URL(URL); //URL of the file

            //keep the start time so we can display how long it took to the Log.
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.d(myTag, "download begining");

            /* Open a connection to that URL. */
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
            //int lenghtOfFile = ucon.getContentLength();

            Log.i(myTag, "Opened Connection");

            /************************************************
             * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
             ************************************************/
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            Log.i(myTag, "Got InputStream and BufferedInputStream");

            /************************************************
             * Define OutputStreams to write to our file.
             ************************************************/

            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            Log.i(myTag, "Got FileOutputStream and BufferedOutputStream");

            /************************************************
             * Start reading the and writing our file.
             ************************************************/
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            //long total = 0;
            int count;
            //loop and read the current chunk
            while ((count = bis.read(data)) != -1) {                
                //keep track of size for progress.
                //total += count;

                //write this chunk
                bos.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            //Have to call flush or the  file can get corrupted.
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();

            Log.d(myTag, "download ready in "
                    + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime))
                    + " milisec");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(myTag, "Error: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

**contactListAdapter.java**

```
package com.atechgeek.genesis.XMLPullParser;

import android.content.Context; import android.graphics.Bitmap; import android.view.LayoutInflater; import android.view.View; import android.view.ViewGroup; import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; import android.widget.ImageView; import android.widget.ProgressBar; import android.widget.RelativeLayout; import android.widget.TextView;

import com.atechgeek.genesis.HelperObj.ContactDetail; import com.atechgeek.genesis.R; import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions; import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader; import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration; import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.FailReason; import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageLoadingListener;

import java.util.List;

/**  * Created by acer on 7/27/2017.  */

public class contactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactDetail> {
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    DisplayImageOptions options;

    public contactListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ContactDetail> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        //Setup the ImageLoader, we'll use this to display our images
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).build();
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(config);

        //Setup options for ImageLoader so it will handle caching for us.
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory()
                .cacheOnDisc()
                .build();
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        RelativeLayout row = (RelativeLayout)convertView;
        if(null==row)
        {
            //no recycled view.....Create one
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row=(RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_site, null);
        }
        //Get our View References
        final ImageView iconImg = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.iconImg);
        TextView txtName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        TextView txtPhoneNo = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
        TextView txtEmail = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        final ProgressBar indicator = (ProgressBar)row.findViewById(R.id.progress);

        //Initially we want the progress indicator visible, and the image invisible
        indicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iconImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        //Setup a listener we can use to swtich from the loading indicator to the Image once it's ready
        ImageLoadingListener listener = new ImageLoadingListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String s, View view) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String s, View view, FailReason failReason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String s, View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
                indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                iconImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String s, View view) {

            }
        };

        //Load the image and use our options so caching is handled.
        imageLoader.displayImage(getItem(position).getImage_url(), iconImg,options, listener);

        //Set the value of textViews
        txtName.setText(getItem(position).getName());
        txtPhoneNo.setText(String.valueOf(getItem(position).getPhone()));
        txtEmail.setText(getItem(position).getEmail());

        return row;
    } }
```

**Contact Detail.java**

```
package com.atechgeek.genesis.HelperObj;

/**
 * Created by Anshul Thakur on 7/27/2017.
 */

public class ContactDetail
{
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String image_url;
    private long phone;
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getImage_url() {
        return image_url;
    }

    public long getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setImage_url(String image_url) {
        this.image_url = image_url;
    }

    public void setPhone(long phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

Now the Main activity **Contacts.java**

```
package com.atechgeek.genesis;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.atechgeek.genesis.XMLPullParser.SitesXMLPullParser;
import com.atechgeek.genesis.XMLPullParser.Downloader;
import com.atechgeek.genesis.XMLPullParser.contactListAdapter;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Contacts extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private ListView contactList;
    private contactListAdapter mAdapter;
    private static ProgressBar bar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
        //to add back button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        contactList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contactPersonList);
        bar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        contactList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                long phoneNumber = mAdapter.getItem(position).getPhone();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:(+91)"+phoneNumber));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        /*
         * If network is available download the xml from the Internet.
         * If not then try to use the local file from last time.
         */
        if(isNetworkAvailable())
        {
            ContactFileDownload download = new ContactFileDownload();
            download.execute();
        }
        else
        {
            mAdapter = new contactListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), -1, SitesXMLPullParser.getContactDetailFromFile(Contacts.this));
            contactList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
    private class ContactFileDownload extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //Download the file
            try {
                Downloader.DownloadFromUrl("https://anshulthakur939.000webhostapp.com/wp-admin/Genesis_App_Data/contactdetail.xml", openFileOutput("ContactDetail.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //setup our Adapter and set it to the ListView.
            mAdapter = new contactListAdapter(Contacts.this, -1, SitesXMLPullParser.getContactDetailFromFile(Contacts.this));
            contactList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

}
```

Its xml **activity_contacts.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Contacts" >
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contactPersonList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and **row_site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconImg"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iconImg"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iconImg"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtName"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iconImg"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtPhone"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.atechgeek.genesis">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/genesis"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/ActivityTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Home" />
        <activity
            android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/ActivityTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SignInActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/ActivityTheme" />

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessaging">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/genesis" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MyNavDrawer"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_nav_drawer"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".EventActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_event"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".EventDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_event_detail"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ChatWindow"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:label="@string/chat_title"
            android:parentActivityName=".MyNavDrawer">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.atechgeek.genesis.MyNavDrawer" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Contacts"
            android:label="@string/contacts_title"
            android:parentActivityName=".MyNavDrawer">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.atechgeek.genesis.MyNavDrawer" />
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

If I create a new project and add these files there then that works fine but when i put it in my project it is not able to work,....
it fetches data only once and then never fetches data from server....
here is the screenshot of project hierarchy ...
[hierarchy of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Miy9y.jpg)

Comment: What does exactly mean "it won't work"? Will it produce some error message? Write something in some log?

Comment: No its not producing any error message...code is running fine if put it in new android project but doesnot work in my android project which i'm working on

Comment: if i make changes in my xml file (to parse) present in server it will automatically update listView next time i open my app (the one i made separate but does not work where I want to (the other one))....